# In Liferay 7.2, how can I set up a role to edit only certain content pages?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

In liferay 7.2, is there a way for a certain user to only have update permissions for certain content pages but not all of them? Just giving Update on the page permissions for that role doesn't seem to be sufficient, unfortunately. There is a role permission called "Pages > Page: Update" which seems to also be necessary, but unfortunately that permission seems to be scoped for the entire site. Short of creating a whole new site, is there any way to have a role with update permission on certain content pages but not all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You could also assign UPDATE permission per page/layout. When you have a certain role, don't assign global UPDATE permission, but use individual resource permission.

In your page tree, choose the desired page and use the [...] context-menu. There is a `Permission` menu entry opening a popup with a bigger permission control table.